# Spawning an Object with State TTS

Tags: lua, assets, lua-table, spawn, tabletop-simulator

I would like to combine two and more objects in the TabletopSimulator. Wenn I spawn the objects I can combine like this page https://kb.tabletopsimulator.com/host-guides/creating-states/. I would like this create with Lua. So I need help... I spawn the objects like here, but I didn`t get two objects with 2 states.

```
function SpawnLevel1(Obj1, ID)
        CID = ID
        spawnparamslvl = {
            type              = 'Custom_Assetbundle',
            position          = Obj1.getPosition(),
            rotation          = Obj1.getRotation(),
            scale             = {x=1, y=1, z=1},
        }
        paramslvl = {
            assetbundle = data[CID].assetbundle,
            type        = 1,
            material    = 0,
        }
        Obj2 = spawnObject(spawnparamslvl)
        obj_name = data[CID].display_name
        Obj2.setDescription(obj_name)
        Obj2.setName(obj_name)
        Obj2.setCustomObject(paramslvl)
        Obj1.addAttachment(Obj2).SetState(1)
    end

function deploy(PID)
  display_name      = data[PID].display_name
  spawnparams = {
      type              = 'Custom_Assetbundle',
      position          = self.getPosition(),
      rotation          = self.getRotation(),
      scale             = {x=1, y=1, z=1},
  }
  params = {
      assetbundle = data[PID].assetbundle,
      type        = 0,
      material    = 0,
  }
    Spawning(spawnparams, params, display_name, PID)
end

function Spawning(spawnparams, params, display_name, PID)
    Obj1 = spawnObject(spawnparamsmain)
    ID = PID
    Level1 = SpawnLevel1(Obj1, ID)
    Obj1.setCustomObject(paramsmain)
    Obj1.setName(display_name)
end
```

Thank you for your help
Radoan

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `spawnObjectData` or `spawnObjectJSON`. The format of the "object data" follows the format of the save file.

Rather than hardcoding the large data structures needed to build an object, I'll use existing objects as templates. This is a common practice that's also reflected by the following common idiom for modifying an existing object:

```lua
local data = obj.getData()
-- Modify `data` here --
obj.destruct()
obj = spawnObjectData({ data = data })
```

The following are the relevant bits of "object data" for states:

```lua
{ -- Object data (current state)
   -- ...
   States = {
      ["1"] = { -- Object data (state 1)
         --- ...
      },
      ["3"] = { -- Object data (state 3)
         -- ...
      },
      ["4"] = { -- Object data (state 4)
         -- ...
      }
   },
   -- ...
}
```

So you could use this:

```lua
function combine_objects(base_obj, objs_to_add)
   if not objs[1] then
      return base_obj
   end

   local data = base_obj.getData()

   if not data.States then
      data.States = { }
   end

   local i = 1
   while data.States[tostring(i)] do i = i + 1 end
   i = i + 1  -- Skip current state.
   while data.States[tostring(i)] do i = i + 1 end

   for _, obj in ipairs(objs_to_add) do
      data.States[tostring(i)] = obj.getData()
      obj.destruct()
      i = i + 1
   end
   
   base_obj.destruct()
   return spawnObjectData({ data = data })
end
```